# Change format of sunrise/sunset from API-reactjs

Tags: reactjs, api, weather

I would like to ask someone could help me here with this error. I've got this error when I try to change format

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sunrise')"

edit. Update: I found out something odd. I have this weather app. it works with current API. U load app and type location (city) and hit enter for search. When weather info is loaded and then I write this code it will console.log sunrise/sunset. but if I write this code before searching location it gives me this error. Data exist for sure. Path is forecast.sys.sunrise or forecast.sys.sunrise. If I write this path in some div it will display. U can check path in API which I use

I want to change format and display only HH:MM.

I am using this [API](https://openweathermap.org/current)

Here is my fetch function

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
const [forecast, setForecast] = useState({});

const search = evt =>{
 if(evt.key === "Enter"){
  fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&appid=${api.key}`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(result => {
    setForecast(result);
    setQuery('');
    console.log(result);
  })
 }
}
```

and here is my code where I try to change format

```
const sunrise = new Date(forecast.sys.sunrise * 1000);
const sunset = new Date(forecast.sys.sunset * 1000);
console.log(sunrise);
console.log(sunset);
console.log(sunrise.getHours());
console.log(sunset.getHours());
```

Thanks for your helps

Comment: what's `forecast.sys.sunrise` returning

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the new Date function is called before the fetch returns your data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).